# EF6 InsertOrUpdate для List<T>

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть операция импорта записей в БД, за раз грузится около 7000 строк. Строки могут обновляться, в таком случае надо заменить старые. Однако я получаю ошибку DuplicateKey (ключ композитный из 3х полей).

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    using (var dbTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            MasterAccount MA = db.MasterAccounts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.AccountId == AccountID);
            if (MA == null)
                return false;

            if (MA.History == null)
                MA.History = MH;
            else
                MA.History.AddRange(MH);

            db.SaveChanges();
            dbTransaction.Commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            dbTransaction.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

//MA.History = List<History>
//MH тоже самое
```

Собственно вопрос как решить подобную задач не проверяя каждый элемент на существование в базе и не обновляя его вручную?*

Comment: `merge` добавляет, если нет, обновляет, если есть

Comment: @SeniorAutomator `Merge` - это что, где искать?

Comment: `GetSession().Merge(T t)`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator `GetSession().Merge(T t)` все равно не ясно откуда это. Можно полный пример?

Comment: @SLY у вас ` Entity Framework` ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator да

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47046/discussion-between-senior-automator-and-syl).

Answer (score 2):

Ответ взят из чата

Нужно проверить есть ли уже такой ID в базе. Если нет, то добавить (`MA.History.AddRange(MH)`) , иначе обновить (`tmp.Update(item)`)

результат автора

```
    using(var db = new Kiwi3Context())
    {
        using(var dbTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try {
                MasterAccount MA = db.MasterAccounts.FirstOrDefault(i = > i.AccountId == AccountID);
                if (MA == null)
                    return false;

                if (MA.MasterHistory == null)
                    MA.MasterHistory = MH;
                else {
                    foreach(var item in MH)
                    {
                        var tmp = MA.MasterHistory.SingleOrDefault(i = > i.Ticket == item.Ticket && i.OpenTime == item.OpenTime
                                && i.Symbol == item.Symbol && i.Type == item.Type && i.Size == item.Size);
                        if (tmp == null)
                            MA.MasterHistory.Add(item);
                        else
                            tmp.Update(item);
                    }
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                dbTransaction.Commit();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dbTransaction.Rollback();
                throw new Exception(e.Message, e.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Все верно, но `tmp.Update(item)` реализуется в самом классе путем копирования каждой переменной, иначе если написать просто `tmp = item` то мы потеряем ссылку на объект и изменения в БД не запишутся. И данный вариант не самый рациональный, возможно проще загрузить всю таблицу в локальный буфер и потом уже проводить сравнения. Все зависит от количества записей в БД и количества записей которые надо вставить\обновить...